# How to hide validation error in React Js upon updating the input field?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, material-ui

I am new to ReactJs and I have a form validated with react-hook-form. Whenever I submit the form, I get the errors displayed which is fine but upon updating the input fields, the error stays. I want the errors to be hidden after change in the input field.
I know it should be done with hooks but since I am new to React, I cannot code my logic.

Here is my code.

```
export default function SimpleCard() {
  const classes = useStyles();
  const { register, handleSubmit, errors, reset } = useForm();
  const onSubmit = (data, event) => {
    event.preventDefault();
    console.log(JSON.stringify(data));
    reset();
  }
  return (
    <div className={classes.card}>
        <Card className={classes.cardBorder} elevation={12}>
        <CardContent>
            <Typography className={classes.title}>
                Log in
                <br/>
                <span className={classes.subtitle}>(Employee Only)</span>
            </Typography>
            <hr/>
            </CardContent>
            <form onSubmit={handleSubmit(onSubmit)} className={classes.root}>
              <TextField
                size="normal"
                placeholder="Enter Your E-mail Address"
                label="Email Address"
                variant="outlined"
                fullWidth
                name="email"
                inputRef={register({
                  required: "E-mail Address is required.",
                })}
                error={Boolean(errors.email)}
                helperText={errors.email?.message}
              />            
              <TextField
                size="normal"
                placeholder="Enter Your Password"
                label="Password"
                variant="outlined"
                type="Password"
                fullWidth
                name="password"
                inputRef={register({
                  required: "Password is required.",
                })}
                error={Boolean(errors.password)}
                helperText={errors.password?.message}
              />
            <div className={classes.dokmaBG}>
                <Button type="submit" variant="contained" size='large' className={classes.dokma}>
                   <b>Login</b> 
                </Button>
            </div>
            </form>
        </Card>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Can someone guide me on how to use hooks to hide the error messages once the input field is updated?

Comment: I think as it is stated in the [documentation](https://react-hook-form.com/api), you can pass `mode` as an option to `useForm` which indicates when the validation should be run. You may want to try `{mode: 'onChange'}` and see if it helps.

Answer (score 0):

OnChange, you can update state error object.

```
const [error, setError] = useState({})



handleChange = (e) => {

let e = {...error}
setError(e)
}
```